# Is there a way to get legitimate but spammy words past filters?

Tags: spam, bulk-email

I have a client who needs to send out email to large lists of opted-in subscribers.  Some of the email content contains words that would ordinarily trigger content-blocking filters and firewalls.

Examples are things like "How to prevent sexual assault" and "Breast cancer awareness".  Overly aggressive filters and spam firewalls would obviously see some words there and prevent delivery.  Is there a way to avoid that?

Answer (score 4):

I doubt you can, because if you can, so can spammers. I suggest you get your other points as low as you possibly can, the following should help you get a lot further:

- [Set an SPF record](http://www.openspf.org/FAQ/Examples)
- [Create a DKIM record](http://www.itworld.com/software/67334/how-deploy-dkim-email-authentication-4-steps)
- Configure your script to send via SMTP
- Make sure you have 100% valid html
- [Test your mail via AllAboutSpam](http://www.allaboutspam.com/email-server-test/)
- [Try submitting to dnswl](http://www.dnswl.org/)
- [Check the SpamAssassin list for other improvements](http://spamassassin.apache.org/tests_3_2_x.html)

Comment: I think the correct link to allaboutspam is http://www.allaboutspam.com/email-server-test/